# Rely on the existence of a package manager or install package via downloading the source?

Tags: shell-script, ubuntu, software-installation, package-management, source-code

I'd like to create a script that is able to install my desired set of packages in any Linux distro (initially create it to run in Ubuntu and later expand it to whichever) and basically function as an environment setup. Examples of such packages would be *zsh, omz, fzf, autocomplete* etc...
My question is this, should I rely on the existence of a package manager (`apt-get`) in order to install the package and just call that through the script or manually `wget` the source files and proceed with the installation? Which do you think is best?

Comment: 1. There's no such thing as "Unix distro" 2. Your tool is unrealistic unless you wanna target specific distros A B C and their specific versions X Y Z - anything beyond that and you script will most likely fail to work.

Comment: Just being curious : Who / what amount of machines/users would want *"**your desired** set of packages"*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd recommend to always prefer the native package manager for anything that needs to link against system libraries, or anything that other things on the target system might link against. Otherwise, you'll be going through the effort of making things work with distro quirks for every single platform you're targeting, and will lead to people having problems if they try to use your version vs the version that a package they've installed requires.

As @ArtemS.Tashkinov says, you need to deal with each target individually. That really does not scale: the GNU Radio community has a tool called PyBOMBS, which tried to do this for but a handful of platforms. It's a maintenance nightmare. We should have gone with existing prefix managers like conda from the start¹ for those use cases where users actually wanted an isolated prefix, and put more effort in coordination with the official distro package maintainers to make the software we shipped installable via apt, yum, pacman, emerge, zypper,... and actually work flawlessly out of the box.

And specifically regarding your software: under no circumstances should you install a hand-compiled zsh to your system path. That's a recipe for nightmarish incompatibilities. Just install the zsh your distro brings.
**A Linux distribution is a software conflict avoidance mechanism** that you should use whether possible. Building things from source and installing them that a user night reasonably install via their package manager leads to conflicts, and thus breaks your user's system.

---

¹ This is my private opinion on it; PyBOMBS1 and PyBOMBS2 still enabled a great deal of great applications! It's definitely cool to have it. It's just been an immense effort, duplicating what larger communities are already doing.

Answer (score 2):

This project is unrealistic because there is an enormous number of Linux distros, and for each distro there are several versions (past, present, and future) which may use a different package manager. (For this last point, think about `rpm`, `yum`, and `dnf` in Red Hat).

And this if you decide to rely on package management tools.

If you, on the other hand, want to download the source for each tool and compile it locally (thus making a Gentoo-like super-distribution) you're guaranteed to get endless headaches because of dependency incompatibilities.

In short, this project is huge and infeasible.

Comment: Ansible provide package-manager-agnostic ways to install packages. Package _names_ may still differ between package managers though.

Comment: @Kusalananda I'd counter that these ansible roles are not package-manager *agnostic*; they're ported to the major package managers/distros

Comment: @MarcusMüller If looking at it from "Ansible's point of view", yes. From the user's point of view, it allows them to not care about ("being agnostic about") what package manager is being used (apart from the naming issue already mentioned). To be clear, I'm thinking about [the `ansible.builtin.package` module in Ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/package_module.html).

Comment: Absolutely! I was even thinking a step further, as in "I install the nginx role, and that role knows which package names to install using ansible functions"